# PHP CRUD API keeps returning Base64 for JSON values

Tags: php, crud

I would like to start off by saying I am completely new to PHP CRUD API's.

I have ran into a problem where a certain MySQL table value "binds", which is stored as JSON in the database, are being outputted in [Base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjXtE.png).

I can't seem to figure out why it is being outputted as Base64, here's the code that I use for the [API](https://hastebin.com/eramekalud.xml)

I apologize if this doesn't provide enough information, I am genuinely confused about what's causing this issue. Please comment if you guys need any more information, thanks.

Comment: This looks like a lot of code, and possibly someone else's code. If you're just learning how to do Create, Read, Update & Delete I recommend just looking at PHP's manual for MYSQLI or PDO and going with that.  

At the end of the day from PHP's point of view you're just running queries and the Create (insert), Read (select), Update (update) and delete (delete) are different query statements within that query itself.  I'm afraid this class might be severely over complicated for your needs.

Comment: I feel like I should have explained what I need this API for.

I was recently given ownership of a Discord bot that is ran in Lua, which in turn uses the API to get/store data.

The original bot owner uses this same API and it works perfectly fine in the sense that it doesn't return JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code from [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) and I'm the author. If your column is identified to have a binary type then the output is base64 encoded. Whether or not it is of a binary type is determined by the code snippet:

```
return (($field->flags & 128) && (($field->type>=249 && $field->type<=252) ||
        ($field->type>=253 && $field->type<=254 && $field->charsetnr==63)));
```

from the `isBinaryType($field)` function, where:

```
128 = BINARY_FLAG
249 = TINY_BLOB
250 = MEDIUM_BLOB
251 = LONG_BLOB
252 = BLOB
253 = VAR_STRING
254 = STRING
63  = BINARY_CHARSET
```

These flags and types are determined by column type and collation. To resolve your issue you probably need to change the collation of the column from "utf8_bin" to "utf8_general_ci".